# Getting the uploaded images in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a class with multiple images that can be uploaded. I am trying to use Bootstrap Carousel for a slide show of the images, but I am having a hard time getting it.

**Models.py**

```
class Content(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    website = models.URLField()
    github = models.URLField()
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
    
def get_image_filename(instance, filename):
    title = instance.post.title
    slug = slugify(title)
    return "post_images/%s-%s" % (slug, filename)


class Images(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Content, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_filename,
                              verbose_name='Image')
```

**Views.py**

```
def home(request):
    content = Content.objects.all()
    name = request.POST.get('name')
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    message = request.POST.get('message')
    if request.method == "POST":
        if not name and not email and not message:
            content = 'name: ' + name + '\n' + 'email: ' + email + '\n' + '\n' + message
            send_mail('Email from Portfolio', content, 'email', ['email'], fail_silently=False)
            messages.success(request, "Your Email has been sent")
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        return render(request, 'appOne/home.html', {'content':content})
    
    
@login_required
def post(request):
 
    ImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(Images,
                                        form=ImageForm, extra=3)
    #'extra' means the number of photos that you can upload   ^
    if request.method == 'POST':
    
        postForm = PostForm(request.POST)
        formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES,
                               queryset=Images.objects.none())
    
        if postForm.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            post_form = postForm.save(commit=False)
            post_form.user = request.user
            post_form.save()
    
            for form in formset.cleaned_data:
                #this helps to not crash if the user   
                #do not upload all the photos
                if form:
                    image = form['image']
                    photo = Images(post=post_form, image=image)
                    photo.save()
            # use django messages framework
            messages.success(request,
                             "Yeeew, check it out on the home page!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
        else:
            print(postForm.errors, formset.errors)
    else:
        postForm = PostForm()
        formset = ImageFormSet(queryset=Images.objects.none())
    return render(request, 'appOne/post.html',
                  {'postForm': postForm, 'formset': formset})
```

**template:**

```
{% extends 'appOne/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
    {%block content%}
    {% for obj in content.images_set.all %}
    <img src="{{ obj.images.url}}" alt="">
    {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
</html>
```

Using the template above, when I tried to go home, it does not show anything.

I am in the process of showing the images. The carousel bootstrap is not yet coded on the template.

Comment: i think you have a mistype `{{ obj.image.url}}` not `{{ obj.images.url}}`

Answer (score 0):

you are using wrong modelField name. replace {{ obj.images.url}} to {{ obj.image.url}}

example:

```
{% extends 'appOne/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
    {%block content%}
    {% for obj in content.images_set.all %}
    <img src="{{ obj.image.url}}" alt="">
    {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
</html>
```

Comment: Still not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: I figured it out. I need to do another loop to get the image. Thank you for your help.